# Bootstrap enlarge model content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so what I'm trying to do is have a button that will enlarge the content inside of the div below so its easier to see for some users. As of right now I have a div that holds one of two collections of content depending on which view is selected (graph or table), and a group of buttons above it that effect the said div (which view you want, close the div, enlarge the div content, or reset the div content). I have the button set up as a modal so it already has a pop up screen that is responsive but i don't know how to go about pulling the content from the div and making it larger than the non-enlarged version. I found a plugin called lightbox but it seems to be only for a thumbnail to fullscreen. This is my code so far

This is the running code:
http://codepen.io/MarkBond/pen/VLpXjB

HTML:

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
      <div class="ibox-title">
        <h5>Elements Map </h5>
        <div class="ibox-tools">
          <div class="dropdown dropdownView">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-purple" type="button" id="dropdownMenuElement" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
              Views
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuElement">
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#1">Map</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#2">List</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-green btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resetElementModal">Reset All</button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="resetElementModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Element Map</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Are you sure you wish to reset the elements?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enlargeElementModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="enlargeElementModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Element Map</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="collapse-link">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content">
        <div class="active content" id="1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt
          condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet
          vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="2">
          Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac
          orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac orci
          quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .btn-green {
  background-color: #70DB70;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #33CC33;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-blue {
  background-color: #6C6CFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #3333FF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-purple {
  background-color: #E57EFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
  background-color: #A55AB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-dropdown-style {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin: 14px 5px 5px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  background: #1ab394;
}

.nav-dropdown-style:hover {
  background: #199d82;
}

.ibox-content > div {
  display: none;
}

.ibox-content > div.active {
  display: block;
}

.dropdownView {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Get all list options
var listOptions = $('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a');

// Attach "click" event
listOptions.click(function (ev) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var divToShow = $(href);

    // Find divs with content
    var contentDivs = divToShow.parent().find('.content');

    // Toggle "active" classes
    contentDivs.removeClass('active');
    divToShow.addClass('active');
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("span.pie").peity("pie", {
        fill: ['#1ab394', '#d7d7d7', '#ffffff']
    })

    var d1 = [[1262304000000, 6], [1264982400000, 3057], [1267401600000, 20434], [1270080000000, 31982], [1272672000000, 26602], [1275350400000, 27826], [1277942400000, 24302], [1280620800000, 24237], [1283299200000, 21004], [1285891200000, 12144], [1288569600000, 10577], [1291161600000, 10295]];
    var d2 = [[1262304000000, 5], [1264982400000, 200], [1267401600000, 1605], [1270080000000, 6129], [1272672000000, 11643], [1275350400000, 19055], [1277942400000, 30062], [1280620800000, 39197], [1283299200000, 37000], [1285891200000, 27000], [1288569600000, 21000], [1291161600000, 17000]];

    var data1 = [
        { label: "Data 1", data: d1, color: '#17a084' },
        { label: "Data 2", data: d2, color: '#127e68' }
    ];
    $.plot($("#flot-chart1"), data1, {
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        opacity: 1
                    }]
                },
            },
            points: {
                width: 0.1,
                show: false
            },
        },
        grid: {
            show: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        legend: {
            show: false,
        }
    });

    var lineData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Example dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 40, 51, 36, 25, 40]
            },
            {
                label: "Example dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.7)",
                pointColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                data: [48, 48, 60, 39, 56, 37, 30]
            }
        ]
    };

    var lineOptions = {
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        bezierCurve: true,
        bezierCurveTension: 0.4,
        pointDot: true,
        pointDotRadius: 4,
        pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
        pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
        datasetStroke: true,
        datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
        datasetFill: true,
        responsive: true,
    };


    var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions);


});
```

Comment: Isn't "float-e-margins' strictly an Inspinia template class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-target="#enlargeElementModal"]').on('click', function(){
         $('#enlargeElementModal .modal-body')
             .html($('.content.active').html());
     });
});
```

CSS:

```
#enlargeElementModal{
  transform:scale(1.3);
}
```

If you can't use `transform:scale(n)` then you could simply use an increased `font-size`.

Here is an updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPBzBW)

Comment: Nice work! But it seems that it enlarges everything, including the button, as well as pushes the top of the modal off the screen. Do you know how to fix this? thanks

Comment: @MarkB I have updated the CodePen (see above) and am now using an increased `font-size` which enlarges just the text and not the buttons

Comment: Yea that does fix it, but I'm not just going to be using just font in the modal, ill be including things like graphs in it. So i like the idea of scale, but right now I'm trying to mess around with it so it scales the modal-body, but I'm getting an error where the text goes outside of the modal. Ill update my code pen so you can check it out: http://codepen.io/MarkBond/pen/VLpXjB

Comment: @MarkB ok I will take a look at it. Slow day at work today ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to get the last bit of this website site working

Comment: I decided to just make the modal 80% width with your code and just ignore the enlarge feature as I cant figure how to make the content inside larger without it distorting the rest of the modal. I updated the pen so you can see what i ended up with. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the $(document).ready function you can put the next code :

```
 $('#enlargeElementModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

 var modal = $(this);
 modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ');
 // this to put the content of the div with the id #1 into the modal
  modal.find('.modal-body').html($('#1').html());
});
```

here are some references good luck http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know how to move the content in there and and you made it so simple. I just need to find how how to adjust the content inside the modal to be larger. Thanks!